# "The signing algorithm <...> is weaker than the minimum accepted <...>" error when using Kentor Saml2 library

Tags: algorithm, owin, signing, kentor-authservices, rsa-sha256

I'm trying SampleOwinApplication of Kentor library for Saml 2 authentication. I'm trying to login by going to http://localhost:57294/AuthServices/SignIn?idp=http%3a%2f%2fstubidp.kentor.se%2fMetadata. When I try to log in I get a strange error:

*The signing algorithm http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 is weaker than the minimum accepted http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1.*

It seems that this error appeared just in recent version (0.20.0) because I have tried that library before and I didn't see that error. Is it a bug or something is missing in configuration?

Answer (score 2):

As described in this issue https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/issues/672

The error message is incorrect. What it should say is

> SHA256 signatures require the algorithm to be registered at the process level. Upgrade to .Net 4.6.2 or call Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.Options.GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures() on startup to register."

Apparently you are receiving a SAML message signed using SHA256 but either you are not running .Net 4.6.2 or you haven't enabled it via the method above.

Comment: Actually I think that there is a bug in the v0.20.0 release that breaks `GlobalEnableSha256XmlSignatures`. But on .NET 4.6.2 it should work.